# I can't define STATICFILES_DIRS using Python to figure out the path

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to define my settings for static/media files using python to get the paths so I don't need different settings on my dev machine and my server.

So I have these settings;

```
import os
from unipath import Path

### PATH CONFIGURATION
# Absolute filesystem path to the top-level project folder
SITE_ROOT = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)

### MEDIA CONFIGURATION
MEDIA_ROOT = SITE_ROOT.child('media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
### END MEDIA CONFIGURATION

### STATIC CONFIGURATION
STATIC_ROOT = SITE_ROOT.child('static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'),
```

My problem is that locally it won't load the static files and the terminal says that `STATICFILES_DIRS` should not contain the `STATICFILES_ROOT`.

Is it possible to get Python to load the paths like this or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code per se, it's just that the point of the [`staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) app is to copy the files from the directories specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` into the directory specified in `STATIC_ROOT`, so it doesn't make much sense to include the `STATIC_ROOT` directory in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.

Unless you're actually using the `staticfiles` app with `./manage.py collectstatic`, you may as well just leave the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting empty, i.e. just change...

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'),
```

...to...

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation, thanks. I've been using Django for over a year & not actually used the static app!

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

```
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/'),
)
```

That should work. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

+1 for both other answers. If you get tired of typing `os.path.bla` a lot here's a shortcut you can position at the top of your settings file (or import from anywhere else)

```
def rel(*x):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    rel('static'),
)
```

Comment: Very clever: also cand do this: `rel = lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), x)` :) Nice tip!